# add telephone numbers only to certain people in array list

Tags: java, arrays

I need to manage a consulting company. The company needs to add tasks that can be assigned to  more than one person(läggtilluppdrag). when i try to print the tasks list (listauppdrag) it works fine when the task is only assigned to one person, but when there's more than one sharing the same  task it only prints out the last person i've added on the task. how do i print them all?

```
public static void läggTillUppdrag(){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Ange uppdrags namn:");
    String namn= sc.nextLine(); 
    System.out.print("Ange uppdrags beskrivning:");
    String beskrivning= sc.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Ange datum:");
    int datum= sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Ange uppdrags timmar:");
    int timmar= sc.nextInt();
    boolean uppfyllt=false;
    Scanner sc2= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Hur många kunder delar på uppdraget?");
    int nummer= sc2.nextInt();
    int totalprocent=0;
    boolean finns=false;
    for (int i=0;i<nummer;i++){
        sc2.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Ange kundens namn:");
        String Knamn= sc2.nextLine();
        for(int h=0;h<KundLista.size();h++){
            if(KundLista.get(h).getNamn().equals(Knamn)){
                finns=true;
                System.out.print("Hur många procent ska "+Knamn+" betala?");
                int procent= sc2.nextInt();
                double total=100.0;
                double Summa=((timmar*9999)*procent)/total;
                System.out.println("Kunden ska betala "+Summa+" kr");
                totalprocent=totalprocent+procent;
                if(totalprocent<100){
                System.out.println("Totalbeloppet är för litet!");
            }
                else if(totalprocent==100){
                    uppfyllt=true;
                    Uppdrag NyUppdrag=new Uppdrag(namn,beskrivning,datum,timmar,Knamn,procent);
                    UppdragLista.add(NyUppdrag);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void listaUppdrag(){
    for(int h=0;h<UppdragLista.size();h++){
        System.out.println(UppdragLista.get(h));
            }
}
```

```
package konsultfirma;

public class Uppdrag {

    private String uppdragsNamn;
    private String uppdragsBeskrivning;
    private int uppdragsDatum;
    private int uppdragsTimmar;
    private String kundensNamn; 
    private int kundensProcent;

    Uppdrag(String namn, String beskrivning, int datum, int timmar, String Knamn, int procent){
        uppdragsNamn = namn;
        uppdragsBeskrivning = beskrivning;
        uppdragsDatum = datum;
        uppdragsTimmar = timmar;
        kundensNamn=Knamn;
        kundensProcent=procent;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "Namn: "+uppdragsNamn+", Beskrivning: " + uppdragsBeskrivning + ", datum: " + uppdragsDatum +", antal timmar: " + uppdragsTimmar+", kundens namn: "+kundensNamn+", kundens procent: "+kundensProcent;
    }

    public String getuppdragsNamn(){
        return uppdragsNamn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please translate the names of the variables, it is very hard for anyone not speaking your native language to help.

Comment: What is `UppdragLista`? post code for it

Comment: uppdragLista is our ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe use an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Uppdrag> userList = new ArrayList();
//Then start adding new elements.
userList.add(new Uppdrag(namn,beskrivning,datum,timmar,Knamn,procent));
//To return all the elements you need to run a loop:
for(int i =0;i<userList.size();i++){
    System.out.println("Namn: "+userList.get(i).uppdragsNamn+", Beskrivning: " 
    + userList.get(i).uppdragsBeskrivning + ", datum: " + userList.get(i).uppdragsDatum +",
    antal timmar: " + userList.get(i).uppdragsTimmar+", kundens namn: 
    "+userList.get(i).kundensNamn+", kundens procent: "+userList.get(i).kundensProcent);
}
```

Comment: should i add this in the main class(firma) or in the tasks class(uppdrag)?